# How to jest test (Body as any).pipe(zlib.createGunzip())?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pipe, ts-jest

I have been working on creating a unit test to test my import function implementation, but I can't get to pass from the `.pipe()` line. Here are some of my function lines for more context:

```
  const { Body } = await s3.send(command);
  console.log('body');
  console.log(Body);
  const input = (Body as any).pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
  console.log('done body');
  const lines = readline.createInterface({
    input,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });
  console.log('done lines');
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
describe('Import function', function () {
  it('Import file', async () => {
    const stream = createReadStream('./tests/data/test.csv');
    const sdkStream = sdkStreamMixin(stream);
    s3Mock.on(GetObjectCommand).resolves({ Body: sdkStream });

    const event: any;
    let context: any;
    const result = await handler(event, context);
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

The `console.log('body');` and `console.log(Body);` lines are being printed and `Body` has the next value:

```
console.log
      ReadStream {
        fd: null,
        path: './tests/data/GLOBAL.csv',
        flags: 'r',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        end: Infinity,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesRead: 0,
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 65536,
          ...
```

Even though `Body` has a value I am getting the next error when I run my test:

```
console.log
      TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
          at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (node:internal/streams/readable:711:8)
```

Any ideas what's going on?

I implemented the s3 read mockup using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-client-mock
After that I have tried to add another `.on` values to the `s3Mock` object but hasn't worked.

Comment: Is `Body` a stream?

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu yes

Comment: May be because createGunzip expects zipped file & you are passing plain csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to move those lines of code to a new file so I could mock that file import

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).